# the Energy functional of a PDE : $-\triangle u +u|u|^{p-1} =f$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

how can I show that the Energy functional of a PDE : $-\triangle u +u|u|^{p-1} =f$ in $\Omega$

$u=0$ in $\partial \Omega$, is : 
$$
E(u)=\int_\Omega\Bigl(\frac12|\nabla u|^2+\frac1{p+1}|u|^{p+1}-f\,u\bigr)dx.
$$
Please :)

Comment: Either differentiate $E$ using the [Gateaux derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative) or multiply the PDE by $u$ and integrate by parts.

Comment: But :$(-\triangle u +u|u|^{p-1})u =fu\Rightarrow \int-\triangle u(x)  u(x) dx+\int |u(x)|^{p+1}dx=\int f (x) u (x) dx\Rightarrow \int |\nabla u (x)|^2 dx +\int |u(x)|^{p+1}dx=\int f (x) u (x) dx $. this my effort, but I don't find the energy function